# How to ingest Delta Lake MetaData into Amundsen Data Discovery Engine?

Tags: python, apache-spark, databricks, delta-lake

I have setup the Amundsen and the UI Works fine. I am trying to run the sample delta lake loader given in the examples in their repository.

```
"""
This is a example script for extracting Delta Lake Metadata Results
"""

from pyhocon import ConfigFactory
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

from databuilder.extractor.delta_lake_metadata_extractor import DeltaLakeMetadataExtractor
from databuilder.job.job import DefaultJob
from databuilder.loader.file_system_neo4j_csv_loader import FsNeo4jCSVLoader
from databuilder.models.table_metadata import DESCRIPTION_NODE_LABEL
from databuilder.publisher import neo4j_csv_publisher
from databuilder.publisher.neo4j_csv_publisher import Neo4jCsvPublisher
from databuilder.task.task import DefaultTask

# NEO4J cluster endpoints
NEO4J_ENDPOINT = 'bolt://localhost:7687/'

neo4j_endpoint = NEO4J_ENDPOINT

neo4j_user = 'neo4j'
neo4j_password = 'test'
cluster_key = 'my_delta_environment'
database = 'delta'
# Or set to empty to do all
schema_list = ['schema1', 'schema2']
# Or set to empty list if you don't have any schemas that you don't want to process
exclude_list = ['bad_schema']


def create_delta_lake_job_config():
    tmp_folder = '/var/tmp/amundsen/table_metadata'
    node_files_folder = f'{tmp_folder}/nodes/'
    relationship_files_folder = f'{tmp_folder}/relationships/'

    job_config = ConfigFactory.from_dict({
        f'extractor.delta_lake_table_metadata.{DeltaLakeMetadataExtractor.CLUSTER_KEY}': cluster_key,
        f'extractor.delta_lake_table_metadata.{DeltaLakeMetadataExtractor.DATABASE_KEY}': database,
        f'extractor.delta_lake_table_metadata.{DeltaLakeMetadataExtractor.SCHEMA_LIST_KEY}': schema_list,
        f'extractor.delta_lake_table_metadata.{DeltaLakeMetadataExtractor.EXCLUDE_LIST_SCHEMAS_KEY}': exclude_list,
        f'loader.filesystem_csv_neo4j.{FsNeo4jCSVLoader.NODE_DIR_PATH}': node_files_folder,
        f'loader.filesystem_csv_neo4j.{FsNeo4jCSVLoader.RELATION_DIR_PATH}': relationship_files_folder,
        f'publisher.neo4j.{neo4j_csv_publisher.NODE_FILES_DIR}': node_files_folder,
        f'publisher.neo4j.{neo4j_csv_publisher.RELATION_FILES_DIR}': relationship_files_folder,
        f'publisher.neo4j.{neo4j_csv_publisher.NEO4J_END_POINT_KEY}': neo4j_endpoint,
        f'publisher.neo4j.{neo4j_csv_publisher.NEO4J_USER}': neo4j_user,
        f'publisher.neo4j.{neo4j_csv_publisher.NEO4J_PASSWORD}': neo4j_password,
        f'publisher.neo4j.{neo4j_csv_publisher.NEO4J_CREATE_ONLY_NODES}': [DESCRIPTION_NODE_LABEL],
        f'publisher.neo4j.job_publish_tag': 'some_unique_tag'  # TO-DO unique tag must be added
    })
    return job_config


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # This assumes you are running on a spark cluster (for example databricks cluster)
    # that is configured with a hive metastore that
    # has pointers to all of your delta tables
    # Because of this, this code CANNOT run as a normal python operator on airflow.
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Amundsen Delta Lake Metadata Extraction").getOrCreate()
    job_config = create_delta_lake_job_config()
    dExtractor = DeltaLakeMetadataExtractor()
    dExtractor.set_spark(spark)
    job = DefaultJob(conf=job_config,
                     task=DefaultTask(extractor=dExtractor, loader=FsNeo4jCSVLoader()),
                     publisher=Neo4jCsvPublisher())
    job.launch()
```

So the above code is the example code given in the Amundsen Repository.

What should be given at *cluster_key* and *database* to connect with my delta lake?

When I run the code I get no errors but no data is ingested into amundsen.

Answer (score 2):

Amundsen's [Delta Lake Metadata Extractor](https://www.amundsen.io/amundsen/databuilder/#delta-lake-metadataextractor) uses hive metastore to lookup the Delta Table's location from its name. What you're constructing with the config is the name of the Delta Table which is passed to Hive to get metadata about the table, specifically where it's located.

This [[issue response]](https://github.com/amundsen-io/amundsen/issues/1655#issuecomment-1010183603) in the Amundsen repo states that the cluster key is arbitrary since it's not part of the Hive table name used to lookup the location of the table. So you can set that to anything you want assuming you don't want to use Amundsen's ability to scope metadata collection to specific clusters.

The other values are all part of the name of the table stored in Hive, relevant lines of code from Amundsen's Delta Lake Metadata Extractor:

- [creating a full table name](https://github.com/amundsen-io/amundsen/blob/main/databuilder/databuilder/extractor/delta_lake_metadata_extractor.py#L247-L248) with [method](https://github.com/amundsen-io/amundsen/blob/main/databuilder/databuilder/extractor/delta_lake_metadata_extractor.py#L95-L96)
- [default values](https://github.com/amundsen-io/amundsen/blob/main/databuilder/databuilder/extractor/delta_lake_metadata_extractor.py#L147-L150)